# Boot Menu Start up OS selection issue

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot

After installing 12.04 and restarting the laptop, I kept getting a blank screen. Then I tried to un-install Ubuntu by EasyBCD method.

When I went into *Disk Management*, there was no partition created. Now when I start my laptop, I get the option to select *Windows* and *Ubuntu* and when I click on Ubuntu, it says the `.mbr` file is not there.

Then I tried to install it again and now on start up, while selecting the OS, I get Windows and Ubuntu twice.

Please help.

I am new to Ubuntu and need it for my college and learning C and that is why trying it out.

Comment: I take you actually *uninstalled* Wubi (which is what I assume you used) , removed the entry with EasyBCD, and reinstalled Wubi?..

Comment: Yes removed with EasyBCD and then reinstatement WUBI ... Now during start up i get 3 options - 1. Windows 2.Ubuntu 3. UBuntu

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. Hey your gonna have to manually set your root (/ main drive) and your swap partition (I set mine to about 500-1GB). Grub will automatically set it up correctly after you do this. I guess they will iron this out in the next release. Nothing free is perfect. But Ubuntu is close, and almost there. Wow, this latest version is so polished! Ugh, Fedora maybe you have met your match....

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you mean by "o manually set your root (/ main drive) and your swap partition (I set mine to about 500-1GB)." I am new to ubuntu . Would realy appreciate if you could provide me with some details.